# ASP.NET with VB.NET adding rows to data table don't remain after postback

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am using ASP.NET with VB.NET and I want the user add several row to data table.

I am trying to add multi row into data table in run time by (textboxes, rad combo box and check box).
I add first row second and third row.
But when I present the data table its show only the last row I enter 
so the table contain only one row.

How do I keep all row in data table not only one row? I tried everything please help.

This is my code:

```
Dim dcItemID = New DataColumn("ItemID", GetType(Int32))
Dim dcUnit = New DataColumn("UnitID", GetType(Int32))
Dim ItemPrice = New DataColumn("ItemPrice", GetType(Int32))
Dim sellprice = New DataColumn("SellPrice", GetType(Int32))

dt.Columns.Add(dcItemID)
dt.Columns.Add(dcUnit)
dt.Columns.Add(ItemPrice)
dt.Columns.Add(sellprice)

dt.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rcItemName.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(rcUnitID.SelectedValue), tbItemPrice.Text, tbSellprice.Text)
```

Comment: I declare it on top of my page before the function page load .What is get and post ?

Comment: OK, I changed the tag to web forms. You are probably creating a fresh table on every post back. You need to do save the datatable in session like [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2116120.aspx?Maintain+data+in+datatable+after+postback)

Comment: Remember that every postback creates with a new instance of your Page class. Your Page class instance and any data it contains is **destroyed** by the time it's rendered for the user in a browser, and brand new one is created and destroyed, including running the entire page life cycle, for every postback.

Comment: @SteveGreene thank for your replay i tried it but its not working any other advice

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks for your replay i know that

Comment: Show the code where you declare the datatable. Based on your problem you are probably recreating it on every post back. What you should be doing is either saving it to session or re-reading the saved entries.

Comment: Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim dt as new DataTable
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        
    End Sub

Comment: Something like that

Comment: I add update panel on my asp code to try fix post back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank u all i found the answer

if any one interested this is my solution :

Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Private dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

Private dr As DataRow = Nothing
Protected Sub btnSaved_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaved.Click


    If ViewState("table") IsNot Nothing Then
        dt = CType(ViewState("table"), DataTable)
    End If
    dr = dt.NewRow()
    dr("ItemPrice") = tbItemPrice.Text
    dr("SellPrice") = tbSellprice.Text
    ' dr("Product_Amount") = txtAmount.Text
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    ViewState("table") = dt
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    dt.Columns.Add("ItemPrice")
    dt.Columns.Add("SellPrice")


End Sub
```

End Class